# Java 8 Nested ParallelStream not working Properly

Tags: java, java-8

```
package com.spse.pricing.client.main;

import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class NestedParalleStream {

    int total = 0; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NestedParalleStream nestedParalleStream = new NestedParalleStream();
        nestedParalleStream.test();
    }


    void test(){

        try{

            IntStream stream1 = IntStream.range(0, 2);
             stream1.parallel().forEach(a ->{
                IntStream stream2 = IntStream.range(0, 2);
                stream2.parallel().forEach(b ->{
                     IntStream stream3 = IntStream.range(0, 2);
                     stream3.parallel().forEach(c ->{
                         //2 * 2 * 2 = 8;
                         total ++;

                     });
                });
            });

             //It should display 8
            System.out.println(total); 

        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Pls help how to customize parallestream to make sure we will get consistency results.

Comment: What does it actually display?

Comment: `It should display 8` ok and what does it display then? Have you tried making `total` [`volatile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html)?

Comment: @kajacx volatile will not help because `a++` is shortcut of `a = a + 1` which is not atomic

Comment: A lot of accusations without much proof.

Comment: Please change the question title.  This is not a bug in Java 8.

Answer (score 5):

Since multiple threads are incrementing `total`, <strike>you must declare it `volatile` to avoid race conditions</strike>

---

**Edit**: volatile makes read / write operations atomic, but `total++` requires mores than one operation. For that reason, you should use an AtomicInteger:

```
AtomicInteger total = new AtomicInteger();
...
total.incrementAndGet();
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem in statement `total ++;` it is invoked in multiple threads simultaneously.

You should protect it with `synchronized` or use `AtomicInteger`

Answer (score 3):

[LongAdder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html) or [LongAccumulator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAccumulator.html) are preferable to `AtomicLong` or `AtomicInteger` where multiple threads are mutating the value and it's intended to be read relatively few times, such as once at the end of the computation. The adder/accumulator objects avoid contention problems that can occur with the atomic objects. (There are corresponding adder/accumulator objects for `double` values.)

There is usually a way to rewrite accumulations using `reduce()` or `collect()`. These are often preferable, especially if the value being accumulated (or collected) isn't a `long` or a `double`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a major problem regarding mutability with the way you are solving it. A better way to solve it the way you want would be as follows:

```
int total = IntStream.range(0,2)
            .parallel()
            .map(i -> {
                return IntStream.range(0,2)
                        .map(j -> {
                            return IntStream.range(0,2)
                                    .map(k -> i * j * k)
                                    .reduce(0,(acc, val) -> acc + 1);
                        }).sum();
            }).sum();
```